# Get directories names and split them in PHP

Tags: php, linux, split, ls

I have two problems.

Problem number one: Linux: I want to get only last folder names using ls:

`Wrong - /home/test/ok/ok1/`

`Right - ok1`

Currently I'm using command:

```
ls -d /home/test/*/*/
```

Problem number two: PHP: I want all directories names (from command's output - point 1) save to separate variables, dividing them into numbers and letters. 
For example we have 3 folders from the previous command:

`ts2 
OK4 
oks67`

I want each of them to write to the variable $foldername, and then receive two additional subvariables $foldername_1 (letter) and $foldername_2 (number)

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: Please post your questions as two separate posts.

Comment: But these problems are interrelated...

Comment: I would point out that this is better done with an associative array that keeps the related directories together in a single data structure rather than polluting your symbol table with several individual variables that although named similarly, no longer carry any relationship to each other.

Comment: What about folder names like "123abc456"?

Answer (score 0):

To address your first problem, use `basename`

```
$ basename /home/test/ok/ok1/
ok1
```